# how to combine two datasets to make one combined plot in python

Tags: python, asammdf

I have a dataset of 6 parameters with 500 values each and I want to combine the two of the datasets to get the road curvature but I am getting an error. Since I am new to python, I am not sure that I am using the correct logic or not. Please guide.

```
from asammdf import MDF
import pandas as pd

mdf = MDF('./Data.mf4')
    
c=['Vhcl.Yaw','Vhcl.a','Car.Road.tx', 'Car.Road.ty', 'Vhcl.v', 'Car.Width']

m = mdf.to_dataframe(channels=c, raster=0.02)

for i in range(0,500):
    mm = m.iloc[i].values

y = pd.concat([mm[2], mm[3]])

plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
print(y)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Comment: What is the shape of `m`?

Comment: @GiuppeP It is (500, 6)

Comment: So a few comments: in the for loop you are overwriting `mm` so that's equivalent to `mm = m.iloc[499].values`. Then `mm[2]` and `mm[3]` are just a number so you can't concate them. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @GiuppeP Thank you for the comments. Actually, I want to concatenate these two: 'Car.Road.tx', 'Car.Road.ty' that is why I used mm at index 2 and 3 but I think this is not the right procedure and I could not figure out the right procedure to do so. Kindly guide

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your dataframe `m`

```py
y = m.iloc[:, 1:3]
```

This will create another dataframe with all the entries in the first component and only the entries from the second and third channel.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved my problem :)